# VBA - search a string in row then copy & paste it to a different column

Tags: excel, vba

_As a newby at VBA, I am trying to search for specific strings in a row from column D then copy it and paste that string in a different column.
I have about 10,000 entries so manually doing it is not efficient.
Strings I'm looking for are "REQ0"s and "RITM0"s.

This is my current code:

```
Option Compare Text
Public Sub Search_For()
Dim cursht

cursht = ActiveSheet.Name
row_number = 1

Do

row_number = row_number + 1
item_description = Sheets(cursht).Range("D" & row_number)
items_copied = Sheets(cursht).Range("F" & row_number)

If InStr(item_description, "REQ0") Then
    Worksheets("cursht").Row(item_description).Copy
    items_copied.Paste
If InStr(item_description, "RITM") Then
    Worksheets("cursht").Row(item_description).Copy
    items_copied.Paste
End If

Loop Until items_description = ""

End Sub
```

Expected results:
[image]

Comment: What is `items` at loop condition?

Comment: Is there a separator between `REQ03723850RITM0548461`?

Comment: Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: @AntiDrondert - loop at item_description which is column D. Edited the code now with that typo error.

Comment: @help-info.de - Yes there is a "space" in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here is a way to do it:

```
Sub Test()

Dim X As Long, LR As Long, POS1 As Long, POS2 As Long

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    LR = .range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For X = 2 To LR
        If InStr(1, .Cells(X, 4), "REQ0") > 0 Then
            POS1 = InStr(1, .Cells(X, 4), "REQ0") 'Get startposition
            POS2 = InStr(POS1, .Cells(X, 4), " ") 'Get positon of space
            If POS2 > 0 Then 'In case there is a space
                .Cells(X, 5) = Mid(.Cells(X, 4), POS1, POS2 - POS1)
            Else 'In case the found value is at end of string
                .Cells(X, 5) = Right(.Cells(X, 4), Len(.Cells(X, 4)) - (POS1 - 1))
            End If
        End If
        If InStr(1, .Cells(X, 4), "RITM") > 0 Then 'Repeat same process for "RITM"
            POS1 = InStr(1, .Cells(X, 4), "RITM")
            POS2 = InStr(POS1, .Cells(X, 4), " ")
            If POS2 > 0 Then
                .Cells(X, 6) = Mid(.Cells(X, 4), POS1, POS2 - POS1)
            Else
                .Cells(X, 6) = Right(.Cells(X, 4), Len(.Cells(X, 4)) - (POS1 - 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next X
End With

End Sub
```

Using Copy/Paste would slow down your procedure significantly.

**EDIT**

A better way might be to just use formulas

Type this formula in E2:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*REQ0*",D2)),MID(D2,FIND("REQ0",D2),11),"")
```

And put this formula in F2:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*RITM*",D2)),MID(D2,FIND("RITM",D2),11),"")
```

Drag both down...

Comment: Genius!Works extremely well